# Kotlin Unsafe and Safe cast operator

Tags: kotlin

why we need `Unsafe` and `Safe` cast operators while only the `Safe` cast operator is enough to keep things simple?

**"Unsafe" cast operator**

```
val x: String = y as String
```

If `y` is null, the code above throws an exception. To make such code correct for null values, use the nullable type on the right-hand side of the cast:

```
val x: String? = y as String?
```

**"Safe" (nullable) cast operator**
To avoid exceptions, use the safe cast operator as? that returns null on failure

```
val x: String? = y as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to cast `String` to `String`. That cast does not make sense.
You just have to use

```
val x: String?
```

if you want to make the string variable `nullable` or you just use

```
val x: String
```

that is not nullable. Also, consider using `val` and `var` to be able to assign new value to your variable.

Comment: I think you get me wrong. My confusion here is why we need the "Unsafe" cast, while the "Safe" (nullable) cast can cover all cases without exception. And the "Unsafe" cast operator should be considered redundant. There may be a few cases that I haven't thought of. You have my thanks if you point it out to me. btw, in my question, it isn't about casting String to String, it's about casting y to String, y can be other types. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to avoid nullability as much as possible. As you can see, the `safe` cast always returns a nullable value.

But you should use the `unsafe` cast carefully - only when you are sure about the type. Another use-case of the `unsafe` cast is when you want to cast some value to it's supertype.